# SQLite & Python - Fastest way of getting all values in column?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm struggling to find a fast way of getting a set of the values (text) in a column in sqlite. My current database has around 600 rows, so I assume the amount of data should not be a major issue. On the other hand, I noticed that it takes significantly longer to get the query if the values are longer in length.

So far I've tried these two options:

```
def get_column_values(self, col, table, option):
    if option == 1:
        pos_values = self.cur.execute('SELECT {} FROM {}'.format(col, table)).fetchall() 
        pos_values = list(set([str(x[0]) for x in pos_values]))
    elif option == 2:
        df = pd.read_sql('SELECT {} FROM {}'.format(col, table), self.conn)
        pos_values = list(set(df[col].values.tolist()))
    return pos_values
```

While the pd.read_sql option is faster, it still can take seconds to get the set.

I also tried creating indexes before querying, which does the query faster. But the time taken to create the indexes makes the option still slower than the pd.read_sql one.

Could you recommend me a better or faster way to achieve this? Could it be a problem of how the database is created?

Comment: I would consider `'SELECT distinct {} FROM {}'`. This would allow you to avoid the list•set•list conversion. I can't profile it for you.

Comment: Hi @DanD. I also tried that. It is a better option indeed, but still a bit slow in some cases. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: How many columns does your table have and are they long strings? Perhaps either breaking the table apart or increasing the page size would help as the entire row has to be read to extract the column values.